# After upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10, holding Super no longer brings up the help overlay. Is it possible that a setting got switched somewhere?

Tags: unity, compiz, 13.10

After upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10, holding <kbd>Super</kbd> no longer brings up the help overlay. Holding <kbd>Super</kbd> worked before upgrading. Tapping the <kbd>Super</kbd> key still brings up the HUD, and holding it down still brings up the Launcher and after a second or so shows the numbers on the applications.

In Compiz Config Manager, under Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Launcher, the Key to show the Dash, Launcher and Help Overlay is set to <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Under Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> General, "Enable Shortcut Hints Overlay" is checked.

Comment: working for me in 13.10: maybe you have some particular setting..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a laptop with a resolution of 1366×768.
Here is the related Launchpad bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1243233.

After testing this issue with an external monitor with a higher resolution, I found that the problem is probably that, in Ubuntu 13.10, the shortcuts overlay became too big to fit in screens with a vertical resolution of 768 or less (the overlay appears in screens with a higher resolution).

Also, if you disable workspaces (in the appearance settings), the shortcuts overlay should start working (because it becomes smaller).

So, you're probably using a laptop, or a monitor with a low resolution (but, nevertheless, it's a bug that needs to be fixed).